# Use Trigger to insert value when Value is inserted into any column in another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a GenreTable:

[image]

I have a "CombinedTable":

[image]

I have a trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] on [dbo].[Genre]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[CombinedTags]([Combined])

   SELECT TOP 1 PodcastGenre
   FROM Genre
    ORDER BY rowID DESC
```

I am trying the trigger so that when a value is in ether of the columns in the "GenreTable" [(MovieGenre), (MusicGenre), (PodcastGenre)]

It inserts the "RowID" into the "ForeignRowID" column of the "CombinedTable" AND the "value" that's being inserted into ether of the columns of the "GenreTable" into the "Combined". Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
AS
declare @rowid int


   declare @insfld varchar(max)

    select @rowid = rowid from inserted
-- assume that only one field has value....
    select @insfld = case when moviegenre is not null then moviegenre
                        when musicgenre is not null then musicgenre
                          else podcastgenre end whichone
                from inserted
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[CombinedTags]([Combined], foreignkeyid)  values
           ( @insfld,@rowid)
```

Comment: This is very close, however still have an issue because some of the columns will end up shorter than the others and will enter the wrong value.

Comment: Note that I declared @insfld as a varchar(max) so I don't lose any characters. What do you mean by 'end up shorter?'